# How do i Put an Image Invisible in only one page

Tags: asp.net, html

Hi I'm trying to put a an Image invisible but only on one page. The images is part of my masterpage. So i thought i could use the image id to set it at false when I'm on that page but i cannot see the id when i'm in the class. It's like it doesn't exist.I'm doing an Asp.net project in VB.

Here the Html code for my banner:

```
 <img alt="" src="pharmacy-banner.jpg" 
                            style="width: 80%; height: 175px; margin-left: 0px" align="middle" 
                            id="Picture" />
```

I don't have any code in Vb.net for the moment here what i tried:

```
Picture.Visible= False
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `runat="server"`:

```
<img alt=""  runat="server"
   src="pharmacy-banner.jpg" 
   style="width: 80%; height: 175px; margin-left: 0px" align="middle" 
   id="Picture" />
```

And then you will be able to access it in the code behind, to set it as hidden in the page you want.

Answer (score 1):

On the particular page add a specific class on the container which holds the image and in the style we can add display:none; or visibility:hidden;

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS only in the content Page:

```
#Picture {
     display: none;
}
```

You must have a `ContentPlaceholder` inside the tag  in the master page.

```
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Then, in the content page you reference this placeholder and add the CSS style:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content_Head" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
          #Picture {
            display: none;
          }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```